# Access string which includes single quote from SQL Server 2008

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I am creating a website in C# (Visual Studio 2010). I have got string values in my database which contain single quotes. I replaced them with double single quotes. But while populating the data into a CheckBoxList, the double single quotes are displayed instead of a single quote.
My query is:

```
SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = select column1 from table1 WHERE column1<>'"+var1+"'";
```

Comment: With _double single quotes_ you mean `''` or `"`? You strings looks like `''WHATEVER''` or `"WHATEVER"` in your database?

Comment: I mean ' ' WHATEVER ' '.

Comment: Okey then updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can escape the quotes using two single quotes like so:

`"select column1 from table1 where column1 <> ''"+var1+"''";`

But remember you're opening yourself up for SQL injection attack. Use SQL Parameters appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

If your `var1` is a variable, your code does not surround it double single quotes.

I think the right syntax should be something like;

```
"select column1 from table1 WHERE column1 <> '" + String.Format("''{0}''", var1) + "'";
```

But more important, you should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: your string will produce the following SQL `select column1 from table1 WHERE column1 <> '"WHATEVER"'`. I don't think the author needs his WHATEVER to be double quoted.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of storing fudged data in your database and then changing it back on output, you should be escaping the single quotes in your query - for MSSQL, single quotes are escaped by doubling them.

However, you'll get a more secure and faster-running query if you parameterise it and assign the value (which now doesn't need escaping) to a SqlParameter object when you make your connection.

Answer (score 0):

I stopped storing the single quotes in the database to double single quotes (' '). Instead, as suggested, I used a parameterized query. I stopped using an SqlDataSource. 
Code:

SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand("select column1 from table1 where column1<>@var1",conn);
cm.Parameters.Add("var1",SqlDbType.VarChar).Value=var1;
rdr=cmd.ExecuteReader();